# Mocking @Resource spring property using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have scenario where I am using @InjectMocks to create instance of SoapServiceClient class in my unit test case. I am trying to create instance of following property in my unit test case.

`@Resource(name="ldapClient") 
private SoapServiceClient soapServiceClient`;

But qualified name "ldapClient" is a component of different type (not SoapServiceClient) ClientFactory. And it has a Overridden function which returns an instance of SoapServiceClient.

```
@Component("ldapClient")
public class ClientFactory implements FactoryBean{
@Override
public Object getInstance() throws Exception {       
    final SoapServiceClient service = new SoapServiceClient(endpoint);
    return service;       
}
}
```

How can I create an instance of SoapServiceClient when I use

```
@InjectMocks
private SoapServiceClient soapServiceClient;
```

It is creating an instance of SoapServiceClient directly rather than creating it through getInstance() method of ClientFactory class. I want @InjectMocks to create instance of SoapServiceClient using ClientFactory getInstance method.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want @InjectMocks to create instance of SoapServiceClient using
>   ClientFactory getInstance method

Why not simply mock the `getInstance()` factory method of `ClientFactory` to return the mocked `SoapServiceClient`.

```
@Mock
ClientFactory clientFactoryMock;
@Mock
SoapServiceClient soapServiceClientMock; 

@Test
public void myTest(){
    ...
   //add record for soapServiceClientMock
   Mockito.when(soapServiceClientMock.xxx()).return(...);
   // and return soapServiceClientMock as getInstance() is invoked        
   Mockito.when(clientFactoryMock.getInstance()).return(soapServiceClientMock);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be mocked using spring's ReflectionTestUtils as below :

```
         ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "soapServiceClient", new ldapClient());
```

Comment: It works perfectly when @Resource annotation fails to pick the instance in unit test container.